# Does Behave (BDD) work with Python 3.4?

Tags: python-2.7, junit, bdd, python-3.4, python-behave

I am using [Behave](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/install.html) (BDD for Python) and have been trying to enable JUnit output without success.  After troubleshooting, I realized that I am getting the following error message **only** when using **Python 3.4**:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 "/Users/myusername/Documents/Programming/Selenium Programming/GMail Project/GMailTests.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/Documents/Programming/Selenium Programming/GMail Project/GMailTests.py", line 62, in <module>
    config = Configuration()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/behave/configuration.py", line 481, in __init__
    load_configuration(self.defaults, verbose=verbose)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/behave/configuration.py", line 394, in load_configuration
    defaults.update(read_configuration(filename))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/behave/configuration.py", line 348, in read_configuration
    result[dest] = cfg.get('behave', dest, use_raw_value)
TypeError: get() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

When I update my project to use Python 2.7 instead, everything works fine.

Here is an important note: this is only causing trouble when I enable the JUnit output in the `behave.ini` config file.  If I take the two lines below out of the config, everything goes fine.  Unfortunately, I need to enable JUnit output for my project:

```
[behave]
junit=true
junit_directory=./JunitReports
```

If you know of any way I could make this work with Python 3.4, I'd love to know about it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say “only Python 3.4”, do you mean “out of any Python”, or just “between Python 2.7 and Python 3.4”?

Comment: I have only tried with Python 2.7 and 3.4, and I have noticed that what I am trying to do is working with 2.7 but not with 3.4.  I have not tested with any version in between.

Comment: I just found this [link](https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/82) that appears to indicate that this is a known issue.  I haven't tried yet any of the mentioned workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I answered my own question in my last comment.  I just wanted to close the thread and provide an official answer as of 8/13/2014: `behave` is **not** fully supported on `Python`**`3.4`**, and even though most of it works fine when installed using `pip3 install behave`, the `JUnit` output option does not function.

There is a known issue for it that has been documented [here](https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/82).

Answer (score 2):

Changing the first line in the 
script: `/usr/local/bin/behave`
to:  `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` #you might want to run which python3

resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use behave-1.2.5.
Many Python3/Unicode related problems were fixed in this release. The tests run just fine on the [CI server with Python 3.4](https://travis-ci.org/behave/behave).

Comment: Is there anywhere we can look to see what is working in python 3.4+ ?